# my animate() function doesnt work

Tags: jquery

I have this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="settings/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="settings/jquery.color.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function addTrack(param) {
        $('.tracklistOff').find('.trackon').clone().insertAfter(($(param).parents('.trackon'))).animate({ backgroundColor: "#FCFCD8" },200);
    }
</script>
```

but unfortunatly, when I call that function, I don't get the animated-color effect!

Instead, I get `cannot read property '0' of undefined` error. If i swap `backgroundColor` with `color` it works. What's happens?

Comment: `animate()` _does_ work. Your usage of it does not!

Comment: Can you post your html as well? Perhaps a jsfiddle.net link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Searching on google suggests that the color plugin is buggy and has issues on Safari/Chrome. You can try using jQuery UI's implementation.

If you don't want to use that, try to make sure you set something as the initial background color for your element.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot dump Javascript into HTML like this. Put your Javascript into `<script type="text/javascript">....</script>` tags and wrap it in a `$(function() { ... });` block to ensure that the DOM is loaded before you work with its nodes.